# How to know time remaining until Anylogic Model is executed

Tags: anylogic

Is there any way one can know the time remaining until Anylogic model completes it's execution in real time using traceln.

I am trying to trigger an anylogic model jar file using vba & want to show a progress bar displaying the Progress of experiment & time remaining until model execution is completed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to know the real time that the model execution will take and us that to show a progress bar.
Felipe showed how to calculate the simulation time based on starttime and endtime set in the sim experiment and the current simulation time.

I don't think there is an easy way to do what you want. based on trial and error you could insert some traceln inside your model and use that to time the progress bar. Though it would change based on your inputs. Even the progress bars you see on microsoft apps / installations are not too accurate so thats never easy.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
double remaingTimeSeconds=getEngine().getStopTime(SECOND)-time(SECOND);
traceln(remaingTimeSeconds);
```

in a more general way, if your model doesnt start at t=0, then you can do the following to get the remaing progress:

```
double totalSimTimeSeconds=getEngine().getStopTime(SECOND)-getEngine().getStartTime(SECOND);
double timeSinceStartSeconds=time(SECOND)-getEngine().getStartTime(SECOND);
double remaingingTimeSeconds=totalSimTimeSeconds-timeSinceStartSeconds;
double fractionRemaining=remaingingTimeSeconds/totalSimTimeSeconds;

traceln(fractionRemaining*100+"%");
```